# How to write shell script to pick any word after specific word

Tags: shell, awk, sed, grep

I am trying to write shell script to find Approved user in Jenkins Pipeline log file. I put here a part of pipeline script. how to pick 'MPPortal Administrator' or any user name following by 'Approved by' words? I am new to shell scripting and I have no idea to do it.

```
Timeout set to expire in 1 hr 30 min
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] input
APPROVE?
Proceed or Abort
Approved by MPPortal Administrator
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // timeout
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // timeout
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Library Policy Evaluation)
[Pipeline]
```

What I tried

```
grep Approved pipeline.log
```

then output was

```
Approved by MPPortal Administrator
```

expected Output:

```
MPPortal Administrator
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed -n 's/^Approved[^[:upper:]]*\(.*\)/\1/p' input_file
MPPortal Administrator
```

Using `awk`

```
$ awk '$1=="Approved" {print $3,$4}' input_file
MPPortal Administrator
```

Using `grep` and `cut`

```
$ grep  '^Approved by' input_file | cut -d' ' -f3-4
MPPortal Administrator
```

Answer (score 0):

There are vaious ways of doing this as the current answers already show. Here are a couple more:

**awk and sed: search line, delete part using `sub`:**

```
$ awk '/Approved by/{sub(/Approved by */,""); print}' file
$ sed '/Approved by/!d;s/Approved by *//'
$ sed -n '/Approved by/s/Approved by *//'
```

**awk: search line, delete part by redefining fields:**

```
$ awk '/Approved by/{$1=$2="";$0=$0;$1=$1;print}' file
```

This searches for the words "Approved by". If those words appear in the line, then delete the first and second field (these are the words "Approved by"). This will keep a couple of spaces before the remainder of the string. So, by reassigning the main record to itself (`$0=$0`), we redefine the fields. This still has the space here, but now we can reassign `$1=$1` which rewrites the record and removes the space. Hacky, but works.

**grep using perl regular expressions:**

```
$ grep -oP "Approved by\s\K.*" file
$ grep -oP "(?<=Approved by).*" file
```

In the first part we search for the full line, but using `\K` we delete everything from the match that comes before this (`\s` is a blank)
The second one uses a look-behind statement.

Answer (score 0):

Two options to consider:

1. Use 'awk'
2. Use grep to locate entry, sed to filter unwanted prefix.

Using awk:

```
awk '$1 == "Approved" { print $3, $4 }' pipeline.log
```

Using grep/sed

```
grep 'Approved' pipeline.log | sed -e 's/^Approved by //'
```

Comment: You do not need `grep` with `sed`.